# link to an email attachment

Tags: hyperlink, email-attachments

Hi I am sending email attachments (using php) and would like to point out to the people that I send the emails to that there are attachments.
I want to do this by displaying a link in the html body of the email, so all they need to do is click the link and there system will try and open/view the attachment.

Does anyone know if this is this possible? 
and if so any pointers/nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question. This may in fact be possible by linking to the internal attachment ID, but what would you expect to happen then? A download dialog to come up? My bet is that most mail clients won't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will not work and it's a security concern, especially since links can be disguised and attachments can be dirty.

Add a big bold title with emphasis on the attachment, most users know how to download these from their (favorite) client.