# Link in email to process an ics invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, icalendar

I have implemented an invitation system in my application, that generates an ical attachment that is sent to the appropriate users.

Is it possible to add a link in the email body that would trigger the processing of the invitation ? (in addition to the extra buttons provided by some email clients)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013995/link-to-an-email-attachment) mentions that for email attachments in the general case it's not possible. Is it still the case for icalendar attachments ?

Other questions suggest using a service like https://www.addevent.com/, but this seems to be more oriented toward "public events", whereas in my case I would need something quite private (only invitations between 2 people), that are expected to be generates quite often (should be able to scale up to 100/day without problem), or it it just me getting a bad impression ?

Comment: When you say trigger the processing of the attachment, I'm guessing you mean for the email client to do something with the attachment (save, import to calendar, etc?)  Why not do it the other way around?  Instead of sending the attachment in the first place, put a link in the body back to your application (some security hashed url) that subscribes them o that event and then provides the ICS file for download?

Answer (score 1):

Dealt with this problem several years ago and there was no way you could force most email client to "process" (trigger "*Add to calendar*" menu).

However, what you want is just make some element in your email trigger that. You can do this by simply linking that element to `.ical` file on your server. The advantage is that you can attache some parameters to your link and generate that event file dynamically. Also, it scales pretty well.

Comment: I actually wasn't planning to store anything server-side (to avoid authentication needs), but I guess that would make things easier indeed, and as you say I could also generate this file on the go.